# SQLCMD is not finding SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

Windows 10: When I run SQLCMD in an elevated command window I get the error:

> Sqlcmd: Error: Microsoft SQL Server Native Client 11.0 : Named Pipes
>   Provider: Could not open a connection to SQL Server [2]. .

I am a complete beginner. I have Visual Studio 2013 installed and started and sqlservr.exe is running. I have not installed anything else - like SQL Server Express. I thought a version of SQL Server 2012 came with Visual Studio 2013. There are 14 SQL Server type things installed (examples: Microsoft SQL Server 2012 Management Objects. Also Microsoft SQL Server 2012 Express LocalDB and Microsoft SQL Server Compact 4.0 SP1 x64 ENU.)

I want to learn SQL Server projects in Visual Studio 2013.

Comment: What syntax you are putting in the command prompt window?

Comment: Can you connect through SQL Server Management Studio? Are named pipes enabled?

Comment: Are you using Windows or SQL authentication to connect?

Comment: Just opened an elevated command window and entered SQLCMD.

Comment: Just opened an elevated command window and entered SQLCMD. I don't know what named pipes are. I tried to find a database or server from within Visual Studio and it did not populate the drop-down box with a server. I might have to download and install SQL Server Express 2012 - but I thought it came with Visual Studio 2013 Ultimate Edition. Isn't authentication moot when SQL Server can't be found?

Comment: `sqlcmd -S.\sqlexpress`, `sqlcmd -S (localdb)\mssqllocaldb`. What will not be running, and what SQLCMD by default connects to, is a local server without an instance name. Also, don't elevate, it's unnecessary.

Comment: Later versions of Visual Studio do start an instance of sqlserver.exe, but its for the localdb engine. I don't think you can connect with sqlcmd like you can with any other sql server.  If you don't have a "SQL Server" in Control Panel -> View Local Services, then you will have to install SQL Express first.

Comment: Also, why are you bothering with an ultimate edition of VS that is 2 versions old? There aren't any compelling features that you can take advantage of that aren't in the free/community versions of VS 2017, and the SSDT project support is way better in later versions of VS.

Answer (score 0):

Use `SQL Server Configuration Manager` to enable Named Pipes.

> SQL Server Configuration Manager (local)
>   SQL Native Client XX.0 Configuration (XXbit)
>   Client Protocols
>   Named Pipes -> Enabled

Then restart the SQL Server instance from `SQL Server Services` menu

Also this will produce a service stop, so make sure it is ok for any users who might be using these databases (but I guess you will be the only one since it is a local instance).

You could also use TCP/IP Protocol instead of Named pipes, if you have to precise which port to open go to `SQL Server Network Configuration`